# Declarative and programmatic SWFLoaders

Tags: apache-flex, swfloader

What's the difference in terms of security between declarative and programmatic SWFLoaders?  In the ff. code, loader1 throws a security exception while loader2 does not.

```
public someFunction(source:String):void
{
  var loader1:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
  loader1.load(source);

  loader2.source = source;
}

...

<mx:SWFLoader id="loader2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference in terms of security. Remember, MXML gets converted to ActionScript by the *mxmlc* compiler before the actual compilation commences, so a declarative SWFLoader (or any other declarative element, for that matter) is just a short-hand way of creating something instead of coding it by hand. You can use the `-compiler.keep-generated-actionscript` mxmlc argument to see what kind of code gets generated from your MXML.

And the reason you're not seeing a runtime error from the `loader2.source = source;` line in that example is that since the previous line of code invokes an error, the execution of that function stops there. Try commenting out the line where you call `loader1.load(source)` and you'll see the next line throw this kind of a SecurityError:

```
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file http://example.com/test.swf cannot access local resource file:///Users/username/Desktop/picture.jpg. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.display::Loader/_load()
    at flash.display::Loader/load()
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/loadContent()
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/load()
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/commitProperties()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```